# blank page in php and no error reporting

Tags: php, error-reporting

```
<?php

if(blablabla == randomtext){blablabla}

?>
```

this code is 100% wrong and no error report and blank page
if i add correct echo statement the page still blank and no error report

```
<?php

if(blablabla == randomtext){blablabla}

echo "Test";

?>
```

i tried something like :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

and

```
error_reporting(-1); // show all
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require 'file_with_parse_error.php';
```

and

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

and i edited the php.ini file and still no error and blank page

Comment: Is your server running? :P In any case, `<?php echo 'test'; ?>` should always work, try that first.

Comment: on any wrong code
like i said in the front of question

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` is for the top of the file, I just edit the php.ini file...

Comment: @odedta yes the server is running and <?php echo 'test'; ?> worked put with wrong line it does not work (blank page)

Comment: Then you have to make sure you set your php.ini errors on, then, restart the server to the file is loaded again.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: What kind of server are you using? IIS? Apache? Xampp? Wamp?

Comment: appserv reinstalling the server will solve the problem ?

Comment: I don't know this server actually, but I guess it should. Besides making sure the file you're running has `.php` extension you've checked everything else.

Comment: solved by reinstalling the server